# Replacing non-ascii dash with hyphen in R

Tags: r

I am reading in XML files into R that have varied formats. I read them in using UTF-8 encoding. I'm having trouble replacing non-ascii negative signs which look like "−". I can't simply expunge non-ascii characters because I want to keep the negative sign. So the gsub below does not work and I've tried lots of different options for the pattern.

```
in_text = "<td align=\"left\" rowspan=\"1\" colspan=\"1\">−0.68 (1.04)</td>"
gsub(pattern='−', replacement='-', in_text)
<td align=\"left\" rowspan=\"1\" colspan=\"1\">−0.68 (1.04)</td>
```

I can see they are non-ASCII:

```
tools::showNonASCII(in_text)
<td align="left" rowspan="1" colspan="1"><e2><88><92>0.68 (1.04)</td>
```

Comment: Under the assumption that you are on WINDOWS - you could look at (identify) the files "correct" encoding eg by opening it in some decent editor, capable of showing the encoding to you (I usually use Notepad++ which has an Encoding main menu entry) and then change it there (in case of Notepad++) or use that info to adjust your "import/read" into R accordingly ie most of the read. functions in R have encoding as a paramteter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear that what you've posted in the question actually has the non-ascii character. I think your source matches this

```
in_text = "<td align=\"left\" rowspan=\"1\" colspan=\"1\">\u22120.68 (1.04)</td>"
in_text
# [1] "<td align=\"left\" rowspan=\"1\" colspan=\"1\">−0.68 (1.04)</td>"
```

The character `"\u2212"` seems to match the output you get from `tools::showNonASCII`. So if you use that escaped character in the replace it should work fine

```
gsub(pattern='\u2212', replacement='-', in_text)
# [1] "<td align=\"left\" rowspan=\"1\" colspan=\"1\">-0.68 (1.04)</td>"
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. How did you know that it was \u2212? Is there a good searchable list of character codes somewhere?

Comment: If you google "utf-8 e2 88 92", That would likely bring up the correct information (for example: https://codepoints.net/U+2212?lang=en). That's the hex code for the character. In R, you use the corresponding code point when using the `\u` notation.